# Json data store in SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to store some data in to SQLite data base. But I can not do that. It give some error. This is my code and please help me to fix this.

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

// url to make request
private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
            String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

            // Phone number is agin JSON Object
            JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
            String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
            String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
            String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
            map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
            map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
            // DataBase Edits
            Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String sqlName = name;
                    String sqlEmail = email;
                    String sqlMobile = mobile;
                    SQLHandler entry = new SQLHandler(
                            AndroidJSONParsingActivity.this);
                    entry.open();
                    entry.createEntry(sqlName, sqlEmail, sqlMobile);
                    entry.close();
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                    TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.email,
                    R.id.mobile });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

}
```

}

here is the SQLOpenHelper class

```
public class SQLHandler {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_MOBILE = "mobile";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Details";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "TopDetails";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDataBase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_MOBILE + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public SQLHandler(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;
}

public SQLHandler open() throws SQLException {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDataBase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ourHelper.close();
}

public void createEntry(String name, String email, String mobile) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    cv.put(KEY_MOBILE, mobile);
    ourDataBase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }
}
```

And JSON Parser

```
public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

    }
}
```

Also this is the single menu item activity

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

// JSON node keys
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get JSON values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
    String cost = in.getStringExtra(TAG_EMAIL);
    String description = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
      TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
      TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
      TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);

        lblName.setText(name);
    lblCost.setText(cost);
    lblDesc.setText(description);


    }
}
```

Thanks. Please help me to correct this.

Comment: some error? what it is?

Comment: What is the error? post your logcat trace

Answer (score 0):

You have initialize class helper in your main activity.